# force AndroidStudio to include default lines in gradle.properties?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Is there any way, to make Android-Studio, that it included some lines (by default) in `gradle.properties`, everytime when it generates a new project?

(for example,  I want these lines to be included):

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Comment: Off-topic: Put this inside $HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties and it gets picked up by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Gradle reads a global and a project `gradle.properties` file. You could add this in the global `gradle.properties` file.

- Global properties location:
  `/User Home Folder/.gradle/gradle.properties`
- Project properties location: `/ProjectRoot/gradle.properties`

From the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties):

> You can place a gradle.properties file in the Gradle user home
>   directory (defined by the “GRADLE_USER_HOME” environment variable,
>   which if not set defaults to USER_HOME/.gradle) or in your project
>   directory.

Comment: there was added, yes, thanks ,seems to do what i needed!